# What's the idiomatic python equivalent of get() for lists?

Tags: python, idioms

Calling get(key) on a dictionary will return None by default if the key isn't present in a dictionary.  What is the idiomatic equivalent for a list, such that if a list is of at least size of the passed in index the element is returned, otherwise None is returned?

To rephrase, what's a more idiomatic/compact version of this function:

```
def get(l, i):
    if i < len(l):
        return l[i]
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: In most cases, I use a `defaultdict` instead of `dict.get()`, and you could come up with a `defaultlist` as well, if that better fit with your use case.

Comment: Why do you think you need this?  Indexing a list is not usually something one speculates about.  Stated another way; lists are usually used in such a way that we apply an action to every element; rather than to a distinguished element (if it is present).  It seems likely that you are using a list for something unusual (perhaps a class would be better?)

Answer (score 7):

Your implementation is [Look Before You Leap](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-lbyl)-style. It's pythonic to [execute the code and catch errors](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp) instead:

```
def get(l, i, d=None):
    try:
        return l[i]
    except IndexError:
        return d
```

Answer (score 3):

If you expect `l[i]` to often not exist, then use:

```
def get(l,i):
    return l[i] if i<len(l) else None
```

If you expect `l[i]` will almost always exist, then use `try...except`:

```
def get(l,i):
    try:
        return l[i] 
    except IndexError:
        return None
```

Rationale: `try...except` is expensive when the exception is raised, but fairly quick otherwise.