# Handling lists and dicts identically - with default

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function which should work with both `list`s and `dict`s:

```
def row2tuple (row, md):
    return (row[md.first], row[md.next])
```

and if `row` is a `list` then `md.first` and `md.next` will be `int`s, and if `row` is a `dict`, they will be `str`ings.

However, this results in an error if `row` is a `dict` and the fields are missing. If I use the `get` method:

```
def row2tuple (row, md):
    return (row.get(md.first), row.get(md.next))
```

it does precisely what I want for `dict`s but it does not work at all for `list`s.

I could do, of course

```
def row2tuple (row, md):
    if isinstance(row,list):
        return (row[md.first], row[md.next])
    return (row.get(md.first), row.get(md.next))
```

but it looks ugly.

Is there a more pythonic/concise way to do that?

Comment: You didn't convert anything to `int` in your second approach?

Comment: Do you want to also handle the case where the user does pass an integer, but the integer is out of range for the list?  With your last example (using `get`), this will still raise an error.

Comment: @Kasramvd: yes, the indexes as supposed to be per-parsed

Comment: @BrenBarn: no, I _do_ want an error in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a "safe lookup" function as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699937/whats-the-idiomatic-python-equivalent-of-get-for-lists) and use that to do the lookups.  It is useful to know that `LookupError` is a superclass of both `KeyError` and `ValueError`, so you can catch either a missing index on either a list or a dict by catching `LookupError`:

```
def safeLookup(container, index):
    try:
        return container[index]
    except LookupError:
        return None

def makeTuple(container, indices):
    return tuple(safeLookup(container, index) for index in indices)
```

Then:

```
>>> makeTuple([1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 4])
(1, 3, None)
>>> makeTuple({'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}, ['x', 'z', 'hoohah'])
(1, 3, None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on `EAFP` manner it's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission. So if you sure that you are just dealing with this two type of object (`list` and `dict`) as a more pythonic way you can use a `try-except` expression:

```
def row2tuple (row, md):
    try:
        return (row[md.first], row[md.next])
    except TypeError:
        return (row.get(md.first), row.get(md.next))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have is fine, but if you like here is an (ever so) slightly more concise alternative:

```
def row2tuple (row, md):
    method = row.__getitem__ if isinstance(row,list) else row.get
    return (method(md.first), method(md.next))
```